# How to check a record belongs to user in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a SQL Query:

```
SELECT r.*, t.title, t.active, ticket_author.username as ticket_author, responser.username, responser.isAdmin, responser.isMod 
FROM `support_tickets_replies` r 
LEFT JOIN `support_tickets` t ON (t.id = r.tid) 
LEFT JOIN `users` ticket_author ON (ticket_author.id = t.uid) 
LEFT JOIN `users` responser ON (responser.id = r.uid) 
WHERE r.tid = [something goes here]
```

I must check, does that ticket belongs to current user. User ID is in `t.uid`. When it's not that user, just returns column "error" with message "Forbidden". It's possible to do with only MySQL?

Comment: A message like 'forbidden' is usually related to permissions.

Comment: I know, but I want to check, does records exists and not belongs to that user (returns error), doesn't exists (return nothing) or exists and belongs to user (return everything).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT r.*, t.title, t.active, ticket_author.username as ticket_author, responser.username, responser.isAdmin, responser.isMod 
FROM `support_tickets_replies` r 
LEFT JOIN `support_tickets` t ON (t.id = r.tid) 
LEFT JOIN `users` ticket_author ON (ticket_author.id = t.uid) 
LEFT JOIN `users` responser ON (responser.id = r.uid) 
WHERE r.tid = [something goes here]
AND t.uid = [User ID goes here]
```

This query will only turn up records that belong to the user.
If the record doesn't belong to the user, it will return nothing.

Comment: I thought about it but in this solution I don't know whether a ticket not belongs to that user, or just doesn't exists.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but whatever it is it probably should be done in the code outside the query. Why does it matter if a ticket exists but doesn't belong to the user?

Comment: I want avoid read tickets what doesn't belongs to user, and do that the most optimally.

Comment: Or maybe it doesn't matter and I can do that outside the query without loss of performance?

Comment: ok, in terms of performance generally the best will be to try to return as few records as you can, so it is better to filter by the user id, that way it won't pick up any tickets that don't belong to the user, and you can let the database engine figure out the most optimal way to do it. overall your query isn't *that* complicated, so I wouldn't worry about performance in this case